# Динамическое создание и удаление потоков

Tags: многопоточность, forth

Как сделать автоматически около 500 000 безымянных потоков и автоматически запустить их, и удалить в последствии? Автоматически, разумеется .

Comment: Следует хотя бы поверхностно ознакомиться с матчастью перед задаванием вопроса.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Именованных [потоков выполнения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) не бывает. Поток автоматически "удаляется" при завершении.

Лексикон работы с потоками ни в каком стандарте Форта не зафиксирован.
Касательно SP-Forth/4 — см. пример в [документации](http://spf.sourceforge.net/docs/intro.ru.html#task). Надо заметить, что словом `TASK:` создается "задача" (а не поток).

Произвольное слово может быть запущено в отдельном потоке словом `LAUNCH ( xt -- )`, которое определяется следующим образом:

```
:NONAME ( xt -- ) CATCH ERROR ; TASK CONSTANT LAUNCHER

: LAUNCH ( xt -- ) \ xt ( -- )
  LAUNCHER START  CloseHandle ERR THROW
; 

\ пример
: t 5 0 DO I . 200 PAUSE LOOP ;
: test 3 0 DO ['] t LAUNCH 150 PAUSE LOOP ;
test
```

При распараллеливании вычисления количество потоков следует соотносить с количеством ядер процессора. И в общем случае — с объемом оперативной памяти, т.к. каждый поток имеет как минимум свой стек (грубо, 1 Мб) — 5e5 потоков это 0.5 терабайт оперативной памяти.